# Change "Generating preview" screen in Wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, loading, preview

I need to change the "Generating preview" screen in wordpress. Both the backgrgound color, the logo and the text. Has anybody succeeded with this?[image]

Comment: What have you tried, researched, etc.? Have you looked at the source code for the page? You will find a `editor-post-preview-button__interstitial-message` class. You can then find `editor.js` which defines `writeInterstitialMessage()`, and finally, how the markup is output. You might be able to hook into the filters to change that markup.

Comment: Hi @chriskirknielsen, yes I found, that a filter could wrap around the .editor-post-preview-button__interstitial-message component, allowing me to completely swap out the Generating preview… UI:

`wp.hooks.addFilter( 'editor.interstitialMessage', function() {
    return wp.element.createElement( 'div', { className: 'my-custom-message' },
        wp.element.createElement( 'p', null, 'Post preview is being generated! ' )
    );
} );`

But I can't get it to work. Have you got any experience in using a filter like this?

Comment: Sadly I haven't tried hooking into the JS-side filters, but make sure your code is loaded onto the page (see if the file is in the DevTool's network list) and work your way through. I'm sorry I can't help more, but interested in seeing if this is possible!

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution:) First I add an action to load an admin.js file

```
function tas_load_custom_wp_admin_style(){
    wp_enqueue_script( 'tas-scripts', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/dist/scripts/admin.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.0.0', true );
}
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'tas_load_custom_wp_admin_style');
```

Then in the admin.js file I can add the filter

```
function generatingPreviewView() {
wp.hooks.addFilter(
  "editor.PostPreview.interstitialMarkup",
  "my-plugin/custom-preview-message",
  customPreviewMessage
);}
  var customPreviewMessage = function () {
  return '<div class="tas-generate-preview">Loading</div>';
};
```

In javascript I embed the svg code from my logo and use inline css to style it. Hope this makes sense:)